# Undefined index: fileToUpload while load a createpost page?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code in which i am creating a post with `title` `description` and `image` and i am storing image in a folder images. all things working fine while i create a post this move file to images folder. `title` , `description` and `imagepath` gone to news folder and so on. but when firstly arrive on createnews.php page this error is shown how to handle this error.

**NOTE: this error is shown on page load after loading post is submitting correctly**

**Error**

Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in E:\Software projects Folder\htdocs\Criclite\createnews.php on line 63
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

**createnews.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add news</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="createnews.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Add Post Details Here</h2>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>
            <p class="error"><?php echo $_GET['error']; ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Post Title"><br>
        <label>Description</label>
        <br>
        <textarea rows="8" cols="100" name="description"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <label >Select image:</label>
        <input type="file"  name="fileToUpload" 
                   value="" />
            <div>
                <button onclick="allnews()" type="submit"name="upload">
                  Submit
                </button>
            </div>  
     </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
  include("db_config.php");
  require_once "header.php";

$target_dir = "images/";
 $file_name = date("U").".jpg";
$target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
$title=$_POST['title'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
    $sql=  "
INSERT INTO `news` ( `title`, `description`, `image`) VALUES ( '".$title."', '".$description."', '".$target_file."')";
if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
}
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: <?php Put ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>  at top of your page and then share the error.

Comment: Your entire php code should only run if the form was submitted.

Comment: Yes, move the closing bracket for "if(isset($_POST["submit"]))" to the end of your PHP code, then it should work, like @Shadow was suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be a clean approach but a quick one. You can just add the following snippet to make sure that the form submission script only executes when the form is posted. You can add this at the beginning of the script.

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])){
  return false;
}
...
```